# Is it possible to "fetch" the arguments used via Mockito.when?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Is it possible to fetch/store what arguments were used when using Mockito.when?

For example this pseudo code:

```
Mockito.when(mock.someMethod(**any string**)).thenReturn(print(** any string **));
```

print would be:

```
public void print(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
Person mockPerson = ...

mockPerson.setName("John");
```

Which would trigger that 'John' would be printed to std out.

Maybe a lame example, but I want to "store"/"use" any arguments the mocked-method would have been called with.

Follow-up question: If not, what other testing frameworks can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) documentation could be interesting for you.

Comment: ArgumentCaptor will allow you to capture the value for later verification, but won't allow you to act on the value in the Return statement.

The original question wanted to do something immediately with the captured value, and not merely verify it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for. Create a custom Answer that uses the invocation target.

```
 when(mock.someMethod(10)).thenAnswer(new Answer<Integer>() {
 public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
     return (Integer) invocation.getArguments()[0];
 }
```

}

Link to Mockito docs: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#then%28org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29